# Creating a vector of R objects

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to pack a few `igraph` graph objects into a vector.

First, I initialize the container

```
x <- vector("list", 10)
```

The I build the vector, by indexing in:

```
for (i in 1:10) x[i] <- igraph::make_full_graph(10)
```

This throws up a lot of warnings like so:

```
Warning messages:
1: In x[i] <- make_full_graph(10) :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

The following works though:

```
for (i in 1:10) x[[i]] <- igraph::make_full_graph(10)
```

My question is: Since I am building a vector of objects, shouldn't `[]` and `[[]]` work similarly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to create a `list` of graph objects.  Here, we don't need to initialize a `list` before

```
lapply(1:10, function(x) igraph::make_full_graph(10))
```

---

Regarding the OP's code, the `list` assignment should be `[[` instead of `[`

```
for (i in 1:10) x[[i]] <- igraph::make_full_graph(10)
```

The reason is that `x[i]` is not extracting the `list` element, it is still a `list` of length 1

```
x[1]
#[[1]]
#NULL
```

where as

```
x[[1]]
#NULL
```